# How to set spark.driver.memory for Spark/Zeppelin on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

When using EMR (with Spark, Zeppelin), changing `spark.driver.memory` in Zeppelin Spark interpreter settings won't work.

I wonder what is the best and quickest way to set Spark driver memory when using EMR web interface (not aws CLI) to create clusters?

Is Bootstrap action could be a solution?
If yes, can you please provide an example of how the bootstrap action file should look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always try to add the following configuration on job flow/cluster creation :

```
[
    {
        "Classification": "spark-defaults",
        "Properties": {
            "spark.driver.memory": "12G"
        }
    }
]
```

You can do this most of the configurations whether for `spark-default`, hadoop `core-site`, etc.

I hope this helps !

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I think it should be a spark configuration rather than a zeppelin one?

Comment: Ok let me update my answer so you can set it in spark conf

Comment: Glad it helped @Rami

Comment: sure it helped! As always ;)

Comment: well, it is a zeppelin configuration after all, because zeppelin is the one that calls spark-submit, but if not configured otherwise, it will use the spark defaults arguments for the spark-submit command. So, rather than setting up zeppelin, this answer solves it by modifying the spark-defaults themselves. Great answer!

Comment: To set the spark defaults using the console, you can use the instructions here (you'll have to scroll a little) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html